# Slicing in 2 different position in a row to make a array from a 24 x 24 matrix

Tags: arrays, slice

I am trying to obtain a array like this

```
array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I have `24 x 24` matrix and I want to make a new array containing different position in a row:
like this:

```
P[[0:2,8:10],[6:8,8:10]]
```

from `0-1` row and `8-9` column `+ 6-7` row and `8-9` column.

I get a syntax error,

```
 File "<input>", line 1

P[[0:2,8:10],[6:8,8:10]]
      ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It works fine if I do this separately i.e.

```
P[0:2,8:10] and P[6:8,8:10]
```

Is it impossible to obtain with slicing method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code!

Comment: I just have a array which is 24 x 24 and I want the values in column 8 and 9 and from lines 0 and 1 and 6 and 8. That what's Im trying to obtain. 

So P = 24 x 24 matrix 

Im trying to get exactly that 
P_1 = P[[0:2,8:10],[6:8,8:10]]

In stead of this:
lamda_9_10 = P_a[0:2,8:10]
lamda_9_10= P_a[6:8,8:10]

I want to minimize the variable and thought I could do that im trying in the question. 

Does it make sense?